# Is there a concept of closure under marginalisation for space-time models

Tags: vector-autoregression, marginal-model

Consider a diagonal VAR(p) model for data at S spatial locations and T time points. The marginal model for the data at a subset of spatial locations is a lower dimensional diagonal VAR(p) model. So in some sense the diagonal VAR(p) model is closed under "spatial" marginalisation. Is this an existing concept?